# Installing SimpLESS in window 7 - "could not query info: Invalid HTTP Status Code (403)"

Tags: less, http-status-code-403

I'm having problem of installing SimpLESS after downloaded from this website: http://wearekiss.com/simpless.

I run from SimpLESS.exe and the error pop up was "could not query info: Invalid HTTP Status Code (403)" Is there any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Comment: You are [not the only one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979632/trouble-to-install-simpless) this is happening to right now.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to try again (perhaps both with the download and the execution). A 403 error is a reply back from the web server that it is refusing the request.

I don't know if that was just a bug at the time you tried to execute or not, but there is not much you can do about it (it is out of your control if a server is refusing to respond). I'm not a server expert, so I don't know if there is some setting on your server that may be causing the other server to refuse the request.

Obviously, this is probably not normal behavior otherwise no one could download SimpLESS and get it working, which is why I first recommend simply trying again to see if things have changed.