# Trouble to install SimpLESS

Tags: css, installation, less, http-status-code-403

I am trying to install SimpLESS on my Windows 7 64bit PC. However, as soon as I tried to run the installer, it popup an error message saying: "Could not query info: Invalid HTTP Status Code (403)". I tried with Google, but didn't found any solution for that.

Do you ever experience this problem before? Any idea what causes that problem? How can I solve it? If worst case I can't get run on my PC, is there any other way to do LESS CSS on my PC?

Thank you.

Comment: I tried using SimpLESS. Used it succesfully for a day or so. Suddenly, it stopped working; now I'm using [WinLess](http://winless.org), which is much more stable and configurable.

Comment: Looks like [it is becoming an epidemic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973181/installing-simpless-in-window-7-could-not-query-info-invalid-http-status-cod).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing same problem.
what i have done is, quit some background running application like torrent etc.
Now its working perfectly.

Click on below link for the same
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/105351/downloading--installing-problem-could-not-query-info-invalid-http-status-code-0